# how to make form to accept icons/images in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

icon is not accepting by form field.
my code is:

```
<input type="file" name="promotion_image" value="<?php echo $mChapterEng; ?>" id="promotion_image" class="form-control">     <?php if (form_error('promotion_image')) { ?><span style="color: #E68F8F;"><?php echo form_error('promotion_image'); ?></span> <?php } ?>
```

please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/mimes.php` set

```
'ico' => array('image/ico', 'image/x-icon'),//check if already exists both then dont add
```

and in your controller add this

`$config['allowed_types'] = 'ico|jpg|png';`

Comment: in controller i have written this,

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('promotion_image', 'Promotion Icon');

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `promotion_code` = 'asdfgg'' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE `promotion_code` = 'asdfgg'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Friends_Around_Admin\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: your query is wrong. see its showing SELECT * WHERE promotion_code = 'asdfgg'   but it should be SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE promotion_code = 'asdfgg'

Comment: please upvote and accept answer if its helpful for u :) @vaishu